# How can I erase Sheet1 Sheet2 and Sheet3 using writetable function in matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

I m using write table function to create an excel file yet i can not erase sheet names which are 1 2 3. How can I erase the Sheet 1-2-3?

writetable(t1,'test2.xlsx','Sheet','a')

writetable(t2,'test2.xlsx','Sheet','b');

writetable(t3,'test2.xlsx','Sheet','c');

when i open the test2 file. i dont want to see Sheet1-2-3. I just want to see Sheetnames which are a b and c.

Comment: You can try the accepted solution [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/215703-changing-the-name-of-the-sheet-in-excel)